# How do I factory reset my Steam Deck?

Tags: steam-deck, steam-os

I've been having some technical issues with my Steam Deck and want to see if factory resetting it to stock SteamOS will solve them. How do I factory reset my Steam Deck?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To factory reset a Steam Deck running SteamOS:

- Press the Steam button
- Select System
- Scroll down to Advanced Settings and select Factory Reset
- Confirm you want to factory reset